# python plotly show x axis tics in slider

Tags: python, plot, plotly, slider

I am using plotly to show some graph. I add a slider as shown in the picture. I would like to add the x values in the axis of the slider as shown in the pic:

[image]

```
    fig.update_layout(xaxis=dict(autorange=True,
                                     range[df.index.to_list()[0], df.index.to_list()[-1]], rangeslider=dict(autorange=True,
                                                  range=[df.index.to_list()[0], df.index.to_list()[-1]],
                                                  bordercolor="red",
                                                  borderwidth=3,
                                                  visible=True,
#### HERE code to show the axis ####),
                                 type="date"),
```

https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/xaxis/#layout-xaxis-rangeselector
I dont see any possibility in the API to show the x axis of the slider, but it should be possible. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is impossible to do with plotly. As you see in the API docs you just sent the link of, there is no attribute like “showxaxis” or the like.